# Tapioca not generating correct RBI file for Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorbet

I'm migrating the way I generate RBI files from Sorbet to Tapioca. However, I am getting a recurring problem across a number of the RBI files for my Rails models. The RBI files seem to be tripping up when trying to produce a signature for a `has_many` relationship.

(Note - it's the RBI file itself rather than the model that is generating the warning)

In the `user.rbi` file, the signature for the `user.plans` has_many association is:

```
    sig { returns(::ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy[Plan]) }
    def plans; end
```

When I run `srb tc`  I see the following error:

```
sorbet/rbi/dsl/user.rbi:110: Method [] does not exist on T.class_of(ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy) https://srb.help/7003
     110 |    sig { returns(::ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy[Plan]) }
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Got T.class_of(ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy) originating from:
    sorbet/rbi/dsl/user.rbi:110:
     110 |    sig { returns(::ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy[Plan]) }
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Did you mean:
    sorbet/rbi/gems/activerecord@6.1.4.1.rbi:3238: ActiveRecord::Delegation#[]
    3238 |  def [](*args, &block); end
```

Comment: Can you try annotating the `plans` association with `sig { returns(::Plan::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy) }` instead?

Comment: Good suggestion - I could do that but it would mean adding manual annotations for all associations which just feels like I'm going to be fighting the natural order of things. I feel Tapioca should be able to deal with this itself....

Comment: That type of annotation came from the latest `sorbet-rails`, running `rake rails_rbi:models[MODEL_NAME]`. I agree, manual annotations are not a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is unfortunately, one of the rough-edges of Tapioca right now.   Since the AR association code was extracted out of Shopify Core, it ended up inheriting that weird generic type for the `CollectionProxy`, without the associated RBI file to actually define the generic type.

We are in the process of fixing this, as we speak, but in the meantime please take a look at this for a workaround: https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca/issues/179#issuecomment-738948320